# PHP class extending of extended class

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, widget

I try to extend Widget_Social_Links class:

```
class Widget_Social_Links extends WP_Widget {

}

class VD_Widget_Social_Links extends Widget_Social_Links {

}
```

and init with `widgets_init` hook

```
function register_vd_social_links_widget() {
register_widget( 'VD_Widget_Social_Links' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_vd_social_links_widget' );
```

But the new widget does not appear in the admin area, what could be the reason?

Comment: We lack information, this seems to be the documented way of doing it. Did you follow the extending guidelines shown [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget/)?

Comment: Yes, I followed WP codex guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is, *a WordPress widget must be an **immediate** child of the `WP_Widget` class*.

Nonetheless, here's one solution that works, but which requires that you add a `register_widget()` function to the `Widget_Social_Links` class.

```
<?php
class Widget_Social_Links extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname'                   => 'widget_social_links',
            'description'                 => 'Social buttons for your site?',
            'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
        );
        parent::__construct( 'social_links', 'Social Links', $widget_ops );
    }

    // ...

    public function register_widget() {
        call_user_func_array( array( parent, '__construct' ), func_get_args() );
    }
}

class VD_Widget_Social_Links extends Widget_Social_Links {
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname'                   => 'vd_widget_social_links',
            'description'                 => 'Social buttons for your site?',
            'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
        );
        parent::register_widget( 'vd_social_links', 'VD Social Links', $widget_ops );
    }

    // ...
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', function () {
    register_widget( 'Widget_Social_Links' );
    register_widget( 'VD_Widget_Social_Links' );
} );
```